# Localization of existing PHP website into subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, localization, translation, gettext

I have a large PHP based website with hundreds of files. All internal links are root relative, in this format:

```
<a href="/news">News Homepage</a>
<a href="/news/article-title-here/">Article<a>
<a href ="/contact/">Contact Us</a>
```

I am planning to localize the website (using gettext) into subdirectory structure, for example French language would point to:

```
<a href="/fr/news">News</a>
<a href="/fr/news/article-title-here/">Article Title</a>
<a href ="/fr/contact/">Contact Us</a>
```

Other languages would similarly point into their relevant subdirectories.

I know I could modify all links and add some sort of language variable, e.g.

```
<a href="<?=$lang;?>/news">News</a>
```

However, I would like to do avoid going through all files and updating all links manually this way. Is there a way to achieve this without modifying the existing links? I looked around and tested some URL Rewrite solutions, `<base-href>` tag based solutions (does not work for root relative links), but could not find anything that would work reliably. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I can set the `$lang` somewhere in header after user changes a language. That's not what I want to do though, I want to avoid using `$lang` at all, and make it work without changing the existing links.

Comment: So you want to support multiple language at the same time and keep link as `<a href="/news">News Homepage</a>`? How would htaccess know what language is to be added?

Comment: Well, that's part of my question. If it's possible to make it work while keeping the link as is e. g. `<a href="/news/">News</a>`.

Comment: Short & simple answer is *NO* Language has to be part of the link.